# Scan first 512 bytes for strings with gnu strings command

Tags: linux, bash, gnu, string

I'm trying to use the GNU strings tool for a clean way to get all strings more then 5 chars in a compiled file but only in the first 512 bytes.

```
strings compiledfile -n 5
```

With the above command you scan the complete file but does someone have a nice bash solution to only scan the first 512 bytes?

Already a big thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(untested)

```
head -c 512 | strings -n 5
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I was thinking of using head but didn't know yet for sure.
good 1.

Answer (score 1):

This should go a long way:

```
dd if=compiledfile bs=512 count=1 | strings -n 5
```

`dd` will only copy the first 512 bytes to to STDOUT, which can then be parsed by `strings`.

Comment: So... I tried this. And it actually didn't work. First of all at the end you get the extra information: 
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes (512 B) copied, 3.2017e-05 s, 16.0 MB/s
and after that the piping toward strings made it not recognise the strings inside the first bytes only those last 3 lines.